# Explained variance with nested data?

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, variance, multilevel-analysis

I have vector representations of text $\vec{y}$ for participant $i$ in condition $j$. The data is unbalanced, though: Some participants are in more conditions than others.

I am interested in the share of variance of $\vec{y}$ explained by `person` vs `condition`.

| person (i) | condition (j) | text ($\vec{y}$) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | $\vec{y_{a,1}}$ |
| a | 2 | $\vec{y_{a,2}}$ |
| a | 3 | $\vec{y_{a,3}}$ |
| b | 3 | $\vec{y_{b,3}}$ |
| c | 2 | $\vec{y_{c,2}}$ |

**What is the best way to assess the share of variance of $\vec{y}$ explained by `person` vs `condition` in R?**